# Probability that a person has a disease

Tags: probability, statistics

Assume that the rate of a disease in the general population is **4 per 10,000.** If a test has been developed with a ***sensitivity of 0.97 and a specificity of 0.96***, then what is the probability that a person has this disease given that they have tested positive?

That's how I've solved it, I'm not sure if it's right though, please help:

Let:

D = {disease}

D' = {no disease}

+= {positive test result}

-= {negative test result}

P(D) = 4/10000

P(no Disease)

P(D') = 1-P(D)

P(D') = 1-4/10000

P(D') = 9996/10000

Sensitivity = 0.97 = P(+ given D)

P(+ given D) = P(+ and D) / P(D)

.97 = P(+ and D) / (4/10000)

P(+ and D) = .97 * 4/10000

P(+ and D) = .000388

Specificity = 0.96 = P(- given D')

P(- given D') = P(- and D') / P(D')

.96 = P(+ and D') / (9996/10000)

P(+ and D') = 0.96 * 9996/10000

P(+ and D') = 0.959616

So,
P(+ given D') = 0.9996 - 0.959616 = 0.039984

P(+) = 0.000388 + 0.039984 = 0.040372

P(D given +) = P(D and +) / P(+)

P(D given +) = 0.000388 / 0.040372

P(D given +) = **0.00961**

I think the final answer looks a little to low...

Comment: That is what it is.  The false positives (4 per 100) are going to far outweight the real positives (4 per 10000).

Answer (score 1):

What you did was correct, but if you've learned Bayes' rule, some of your work was kind of unnecessary.

A problem like this is a very common Bayes' rule problem/example, as it teaches an important lesson: even with a very accurate test, false positives can be very common if the thing being tested for is rare.